# Did I install the wrong ISO? 64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image vs 32-bit PC (i386) desktop image

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, system-installation, 64-bit

I just made a Linux dual boot using an ISO to put it on its own partition. I got the ISO from [this site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/). It is Ubuntu 14.04.

I installed the 64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image because I have a 64-bit Operating system x64 processor.
However, I realized that their ISO for 32-bit PC (i386) desktop image says this is the one you want for Windows and Intel.
My primary partition is Windows 10. My computer has an Intel (R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @2.50 GHz 2.70 GHz and is an Acer Aspire E5-575G Signature Edition. Ram 8 GB.

Did I make a mistake installing the 64 bit one since I do not have AMD? Or is it ok? How do I check in Linux if it's working properly with my processor?

Thanks!

Edit: It seems like the consensus online is 64 bit, but I just want to confirm this is ok for my specific computer.

Comment: This is not a matter of opinion/consensus. It's as simple as use a 64-bit OS for any 64-bit hardware (although a 32-bit OSD can also be used but **shouldn't** unless you have a very specific reason for that) and use 32-bit OS for any 32-bit hardware (no alternatives here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

amd64 is for all x86 based 64-bit computers (including intel) it is called AMD because AMD initiated the 64-bit CPU and command structure.
i386 is for all x86 based 32-bit computers (including AMD).
Dual booting with windows has no impact on which you use.
Though it is advisable to have both windows and linux booting in the same mode:
ie. legacy vs EFI and 32-bit vs 64-bit.

If it boots and runs then it's working properly. Aside from some possible driver tweaks for hardware.

Considering that you have 8 GB RAM, 64-bit is the best choice. 32-bit can only access/address 3.7 GB.